# Generic Java SAML 2.0 token consumer API

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml

I've already implemented a Java Servlet Filter that consumes tokens from a PingFederate (PF) server using the PF supplied Java API. This makes my application able to serve the Service Provider application in a PF SSO setup. PingFederates API allows me to do simple things like this:

```
    Agent agent = new Agent("agent-config.txt");
    MultiMap multiUserInfo = agent.readTokenToMultiMap(request);
```

MultiMap will be a map of the attributes of the token, or null if no token was passed to the request parameters. All I have to do now is map the attributes to my applications User model. agent-config.txt is a file generated by PingFederate when configuring it.

Different clients are now asking for similar SSO solutions to this, but using different SAML implementations.

Do you know about a generic API that will do similar things but be able to consume tokens from more than one SAML implementation?

Does anyone know if it's possible to use PFs API to consume tokens from other SAML implementations, such as ADFS, OpenSAML?

Answer (score 1):

Sindri -

This response is probably a little late but I didn't want it to go unanswered:

PingFederate can consume SAML 1.x/2.0/WS-Federation tokens and abstract/convert them to the token format you are currently integrating your app with. So from your applications point of view, you are done coding and 95% of the work is done. You'd just need to setup a new "connection" inside of PingFederate to tell the server to consume the particular standards-based message coming from your trusted partner.

Since this is standards-based interop, PingFederate can consume messages from (or generate to) *all* compliant SAML 1.x/2.0/WS-Federation Identity Providers (ie, ADFSv1 &v2, OpenSAML, IBM TFIM, etc etc etc) by walking through our web-based GUI wizard.

HTH -
Ian Barnett

Comment: Not really to late since none of the other implementations have happened yet. The reason for the question was that I wanted to be able to use the same solution for different clients irrespective of what SAML implementation they are using. Telling a client that is using ADFS to buy a PF license to translate the tokens is not really an option.

Comment: Sindri - Just to make sure I made myself clear: Your customers are free to use any SAML compliant software on their end. They can also choose to use ADFSv1 (for WS-Fed). A single instance of PF running in *your* infrastructure can handle all the Federation specifications your customers may be using. There is no requirement that your customers use PingFederate. Feel free to contact us directly for more information.